# Images are overlapping in the UITableView how to fix this?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uiimageview, sdwebimage

In the UITableviewcell images are shown using ***[SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)***.
Sometimes images are overlapped/Duplicated in the UITableview.

**Using below code in - cellForRowAtIndexPath:**

```
[cell.imgView sd_setImageWithURL:url placeholderImage:ImagePlaceholder options:SDWebImageRefreshCached completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) {
   [cell.imgView setImage:image];
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally this never happened to me but if this is happening your side please remove content from imageview then set image

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is in your table view cell class.
Post your code please.

Check if your cellClass has the method prepareForReuse.

it should have something like this:

```
override prepareForReuse() {
    someLabel.text = ""
    someImage.image = nil
}
```